# LabVIEW Timestamp calculations equivalents in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, labview

I am trying to subtract one timestamp from another timestamp. When I did this using LabVIEW,the difference as "-21207.3".

Refer to the image attached:

[image]

Now I want to replicate the exact same operation using .NET. What can I do in order to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert timestamp to double type - this is what LabVIEW does, when you do substraction in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar in C# using DateTime objects.  Subtraction of those gives a TimeSpan object, which can get you the total seconds difference (which is the same as LabVIEW).

Example:

```cs
DateTime a = new DateTime(2019, 1, 17, 12, 24, 30, 850);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2019, 1, 17, 18, 17, 58, 150);
TimeSpan difference = a - b;
double seconds = difference.TotalSeconds; // -21207.3
```